# value auto update when input is changed when using usefieldarray in react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

When working with useFieldArray in React-hook-form, I have troubles:

- The first time, after click button Add, value is set and render on UI
- However, when I edit on input is added before, the value auto update although I'm not onClick to button Add. How to fix? Thanks
  [enter image description here]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/r[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCbmP.jpg)IJEC.jpg)

I have used state to save but it not working as I expect.